# CMake: link order of imported targets incorrect

Tags: cmake

I have the following scenario:

- I import two prebuilt libraries into my project (`libA`, `libB`)
- `libB` has a dependency on `libA`
- The executable depends on both `libA` and `libB`

However, **the relative linking order in my link.txt is incorrect**

```
/usr/bin/c++     CMakeFiles/bin.dir/main.cpp.o  -o bin ../libA.a ../libB.a
```

I would expect `libA.a` to be listed after `libB.a`.
The CMakeLists.txt looks something along the following lines

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)
project(cmake_test)
set(lib_dir ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})

add_library(MY::libA IMPORTED INTERFACE)
set_target_properties(MY::libA PROPERTIES INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES "${lib_dir}/libA.a")

add_library(MY::libB IMPORTED INTERFACE)
set_target_properties(MY::libB PROPERTIES INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES "MY::libA;${lib_dir}/libB.a")

add_executable(bin ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(bin PUBLIC MY::libB MY::libA)
```

---

Below a description of my attempts to solve the problem. Some without success and some with sucecss but using modifications that render the code usless for the production environment.

Successful attempts:

- Remove the depedency of `bin` on `libA` (i.e. replace the last line by `target_link_libraries(bin PUBLIC MY::libB)`. This works but I cannot remove the dependency in real code.
- Replace the target type `IMPORTED INTERFACE` by `IMPORTED STATIC`. Use `IMPORTED_LOCATION` instead of `INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES` and use `target_link_libraries` to express the dependency of `libB` on `libA`. In this case the `link.txt` yields: `[...] -o bin ../libA.a ../libB.a ../libA.a`. As soon as I revert the target type for `libB` the link order breaks down again. In the production environment, however, one of the targets is created by conan as `IMPORTED INTERFACE`.

Attempts without success (same behaviour as described):

- Create a separate `IMPORTED` target (use `IMPORTED_LOCATION`) for every lib and group them inside an `INTERFACE` target
- Sprinkle the code with `ADD_DEPENDENCIES`
- Remove `libA` from the `INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES` in line 9 and use `target_link_libraries(MY::libB INTERFACE MY::libA)` instead. Same result.

---

Example code that shows the same failure using `INTERFACES` as a building block

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)
project(cmake_test)
set(lib_dir ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})

# libA
add_library(MY::libA_file1 IMPORTED STATIC)
set_target_properties(MY::libA_file1 PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION "${lib_dir}/libA.a")

add_library(libA INTERFACE)
target_link_libraries(libA INTERFACE MY::libA_file1)

# libB
add_library(MY::libB_file1 IMPORTED STATIC)
set_target_properties(MY::libB_file1 PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION "${lib_dir}/libB.a")

add_library(libB INTERFACE)
target_link_libraries(libB INTERFACE MY::libB_file1 libA)


add_executable(bin ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(bin PUBLIC libA libB)
```

Comment: @Tsyvarev thanks for sharing the thread but unless I miss the obvious it emphasizes my point. Quote "if library A depends on library B, then libA MUST appear before libB in the linker flags." In my example using `A=libB` and `B=libA` (unfortunate naming), I come to the conclusion: libB must appear before libA i.e. `libA` must come after `libB`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You incorrectly think about *INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES* property as a "content" of the library's target, which is ordered by `target_link_libraries` call.

Using

```
target_link_libraries(MY::libB INTERFACE MY::libA)
```

you setup link dependency between library targets `MY::libB` and `MY::libA`. That is, "content" of `MY::libB` target should come before "content" of `MY::libA` target in the linking command line.

But *INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES* property is **NOT** a "content" of the library target! It is just an additional link dependency.

As opposite, *IMPORTED_LOCATION* (for non-*INTERFACE* *IMPORTED* target) is a "content" of the library, and `target_link_libraries` affects on its ordering.

It seems that you cannot add link dependency for a library, using *INTERFACE* library target. You should use *IMPORTED* library target for that purpose:

```
# Collect libraries related to 'libA'
file(GLOB libs_A "${lib_dir}/libA*.a")
# For each library create IMPORTED target with IMPORTED_LOCATION property.
set(libs_A_targets)
foreach(lib_A ${libs_A})
    # Form a unique name for the IMPORTED target: subtarget_A_*
    string(REGEX REPLACE "^${lib_dir}/libA([^.]*).a$" "subtarget_A_\\1" lib_A_target ${lib_A})
    # Create a target with this name
    add_library(${lib_A_target} STATIC IMPORTED)
    set_target_properties(${lib_A_target} PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${lib_A})
    # And add the target into the list
    list(APPEND libs_A_targets ${lib_A_target})
endforeach()

# In a similar way collect libraries for libB.
set(lib_B_targets ...)

# Now link each libB* library with each libA*.
foreach(lib_B_target ${libs_B_targets})
    target_link_libraries(${lib_B_target} INTERFACE ${libs_A_targets})
endforeach()

# Now interface libraries, which combine libA* and libB*, can be created
add_library(libA INTERFACE)
target_link_libraries(libA INTERFACE ${libs_A_targets})

add_library(libB INTERFACE)
target_link_libraries(libB INTERFACE ${libs_B_targets})

# Now these INTERFACE libraries can be linked into an executable in any order
add_executable(bin ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(bin PUBLIC libA libB)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I already had that suspicion. However, how can I solve the problem if I have multiple libs that I want to import? If I import a single lib using `IMPORT_LOCATION` I get indeed the correct result (point 2 of my success-list). In the real code, however, I have a usecase of importing multiple libs. I tried two approaches: 1) Putting one lib as IMPORTED_LOCATION and the rest in its INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES. 2) Creating multiple IMPORTED targets and "grouping" them in a single INTERFACE target. Both approach fail me. Can this be solved without importing+linking each lib individually?

Comment: "Can this be solved without importing+linking each lib individually?" - As far as I understand, you cannot. If you need to link several libraries with a single one, you may use `foreach` loop. You still may wrap several *IMPORTED* library targets into *INTERFACE* one, so linking with that single library would automatically link with all *IMPORTED* libraries, and order of those *IMPORTED* libraries would be correct.

Comment: That is terrible news :( I cannot believe there is no mechanism for such an obvious use case. How can one 1) Grouping together multiple libs into a target and export them (as a library builder) 2) Or build higher level abstractions? I read all the time about modern CMake but if this simple building block cannot be realized then I don't understand how one can ever move past the terrifying usage of global variables and spreading them all over the place.

Comment: just for the sake of completeness I have attached a slightly altered example where I try to order dependencies in INTERFACES. However, as soon as I reach the point that one interface depends on another one, the logic starts to break down again. So in the above example I have a libA with multiple libs and libB with multiple libs (one of them could be CUDA, another one OpenCV). When I link two interfaces together, the order is not consistent anymore

Comment: Not sure that I understand your problem. If you are developer of CUDA, and know that your libraries should be linked with OpenCV, you need to link every your library with OpenCV separately. (You may use `link_libraries` or `foreach` commands for reduce copy-pasting). Then you may export your libraries. Additionally, you may create an *INTERFACE* library which combines your libraries together, and export it too. When a user imports your *INTERFACE* library and links with it, he/she will get desired effect.

Comment: Let's assume I want to create a CUDA target for convience and I glob the necessary lib files manually (let's skim over the fact whether that's a good idea). This could be `libA` in the second example. I also build opencv and indicate that the library depends on cuda (opencv could be `libB` in the second example). Finally I build my executable (`bin` in the example) and express the dependency on both cuda and opencv. The second example I posted should be a minimal example to reflect this scenario. Unfortunately it does not produce the desired effect for me but instead the link order is swapped

Comment: So you are neither a library builder (how builds lib files, not globs them) nor a library "common user", who uses `find_package()` for locate the library with all its dependencies. However, globbing library files doesn't prevent you from creating  separated *IMPORTED* targets (with auto-generated names) for every library file, and adjusting proper link dependencies between these targets. After that you may freely combine desired *IMPORTED* targets into *INTERFACE* ones.

Comment: I have added the example of correct linking of globbed libraries.